# show images on site whick located in another server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I have `ASP.NET WebApi(MVC)` application. On the site I need to show images. This images located on a separate server in the local network. I've tried the following:

```
<img src='file://///server_name/...'>
```

I tried various `src` addresses and only the one worked, but only in the `IE`, I got error in the `Chrome` and in the `Firefox`. I know it's security limitations.

And, I have question, What is best approach to get images from the separate server?  I have WCF applciation also on main server. May be there are exist some way or may be to write console application(or another one web applciation) and host it on the images server, and it's applciation will serve http requesst from my main site? The perfomance is main goal for me.
I can't move images because there are hundreds terabytes. And I don't want to use `ASP.NET Impersonation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map a Virtual Directory in IIS Manager. More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb763173(v=vs.100).aspx).

And then reference the image:

```
<img src='/MyVirtualDirectory/photo.jpg'>
```